# adding browsercaching for subdomain cnd

Tags: caching, browser, cdn

I am using this in my htaccess file to manage browser caching

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Problem is, it doesnt effect files coming from my local cdn networks, eg

```
cdn.mydmoain.com
cdn1.mydomain.com
cdn2.mydomain.com
```

How can i modify my htaccess to manage this?